# MS Charts: Possible to reduce tooltip delay?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, tooltip, mschart

I am using Microsoft Charts to display a column chart with tooltips. However, I would like to reduce (or completely remove) the popup delay for the tooltips. Is this possible?

```
serie.Points[i++].ToolTip = wi.DateString + ": " + wi.Duration + " mins";
//Something like this?
serie.Points[i++].ToolTipDelay = 0;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft Charting is a derivation of Dundas charting software version 5.5.  [Reference](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexgor/archive/2008/11/07/microsoft-chart-control-vs-dundas-chart-control.aspx)

As such, when I cannot find anything in the microsoft documentation, I often try to check out Dundas tech support to see if the issue has been covered.

According to this post*, what you want cannot be done:

http://support2.dundas.com/forum/tm.aspx?m=10709

*That is if the Dundas code base in question on that site is unchanged in those areas to the Microsoft acquisition.

Reference:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexgor/archive/2008/11/07/microsoft-chart-control-vs-dundas-chart-control.aspx